# Get the second largest value of column B if column A value is null for the largest value of column B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
case 1
Table AB
column A    column B
1               4
2               5
3               6

case 2
Table AB
column A    column B
1               4
2               5
NULL            6
```

For case 1, I need the value 6, I will select max(columnB) from AB.
For case 2, I need the value 5 because max(columnB) which is 6 has a NULL value in columnA , so I want the second largest of columnB which is 5 and it corresponding columnA value is not null. Only the largest value of columnB will have a NULL value in columnA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would return the expected result in both cases:

```
select max(columnB) from tableAB where columnA is not null
```

The query phrases as: get the maximum value of `columnB` where `columnA` is not null.